# How to convert rectangle table positions to excel

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have a program in python which reads some document and returns me the all the table rectangles (even empty) like this photo:

[image: table]

every rectangle has its own coordinates (x,y,h,w) and a text label.

The actual goal is to convert that table (a set of coordinates and labels) to a excel table.  **How can I do and algorith for that purpose?**

Comment: You have to transpose `(x,y) ` into `'A1'` or `'R1C1'` notation. `(...,...,h,...)` becomes `row.dimension.height`, `(...,...,...,w)` becomes `column.dimension.width`.

Comment: @stovfl do you have any documentation to read?

Comment: [Named_cells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spreadsheet#Named_cells), [RowDimension](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.dimensions.html?highlight=rowdimension#openpyxl.worksheet.dimensions.RowDimension), [ColumnDimension](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.dimensions.html?highlight=rowdimension#openpyxl.worksheet.dimensions.ColumnDimension)